# White space between tiles in heatplot ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I have this heatplot that I've generated using ggplot2.

[image]
What I would like to do is to add white space between the variables listed in capital letters and the variables listed in lower case letters so as to separate these two categories. I still want the tiles to be of equal width.

The code I've used to generate the plot is:

```
ggplot(mockdata, aes(variable, Measurement)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = mockdata$plotval), colour = "dark red")  + scale_fill_gradient2(limits=c(-20, 20),high = "firebrick3", low = "dodgerblue4") + 
  theme_minimal() + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=28, angle=90), axis.text.y=element_text(size=28)) + 
  labs(title="", x="", y="", fill="")
```

And my data looks as follows:

```
> head(mockdata)    Measurement variable         Pval       effect
> direction    plotval category 21          20        A 4.511987e+04
> -0.004892941        -1 -4.6543678 Measured 22          19        A 3.436853e-08  0.054344854         1  7.4638390 Measured 23          18        A 1.465755e+00  0.355139910         1 -0.1660613 Measured 24         
> 17        A 7.006222e-04 -0.079390247        -1  3.1545161 Measured 25
> 16        A 4.705051e-04 -0.017708611        -1  3.3274357 Measured 26
> 15        A 2.301113e+03 -0.022934623        -1 -3.3619379 Measured
```

PS. While it is strictly another question, I would also like to edit the legend so that it ranges simply from 0-20 and is split in two vertically, showing on one side the red gradient and the blue gradient on the other.

Thank you very much for your help.

Edit: dput output as requested

```
    dput(mockdata)
structure(list(Measurement = structure(c(20L, 19L, 18L, 17L, 
16L, 15L, 14L, 13L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 20L, 19L, 18L, 17L, 16L, 15L, 14L, 13L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 
9L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 20L, 19L, 18L, 17L, 16L, 
15L, 14L, 13L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 20L, 19L, 18L, 17L, 16L, 15L, 14L, 13L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 
8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 20L, 19L, 18L, 17L, 16L, 15L, 
14L, 13L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
20L, 19L, 18L, 17L, 16L, 15L, 14L, 13L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 
7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 20L, 19L, 18L, 17L, 16L, 15L, 14L, 
13L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 20L, 
19L, 18L, 17L, 16L, 15L, 14L, 13L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 
6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 20L, 19L, 18L, 17L, 16L, 15L, 14L, 13L, 
12L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", 
"25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", 
"36", "37", "38", "39", "40"), class = "factor"), variable = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", 
"f"), class = "factor"), Pval = c(45119.8699435164, 3.43685309800565e-08, 
1.46575455003134, 0.000700622204341352, 0.000470505115493356, 
2301.1126328306, 4.54797845872279e-09, 2.82713540460051, 7.27455376527109, 
0.000708124149686762, 2.42898037459018, 129.848099736546, 0.199979430821282, 
3.14108095159057, 1.27073870790998, 107.060952494286, 5853.27997745224, 
0.0742582348172777, 0.179994821770633, 896.77644657471, 23.2401456908433, 
1.04257158400361e-05, 0.818717078694074, 0.000516863241751892, 
0.445544049614064, 37.9699212955842, 4.87750761132064, 0.138732186303325, 
0.0185924820003653, 30.8203248121754, 2.40190754411345, 61.2579350060232, 
6.44618209352764, 1047821.38958175, 704454.528072486, 1184.40676026588, 
9.27799786552194, 244051.746539605, 375048.779613815, 9134.54101073437, 
3.11905288061898e-08, 2.00150860109179e-05, 7.0931638758186e-05, 
2.43242155771004, 1602.73424833609, 6.02923321145412, 3.21794638623681, 
39545.9388361236, 475.781444413131, 455.686197237482, 4.67829129583755, 
909.58298359142, 2.02989433872695e-12, 0.000760836775114312, 
0.000112864936813818, 0.00189775331609849, 0.0815921243521161, 
31.0427655620544, 64.1785732227039, 0.00217933417639979, 0.32663419999951, 
2.54891270451988e-07, 8.48612397192046e-08, 0.370184441863085, 
0.0773444299723239, 1580.93083600716, 25.4862794021994, 30.2642707469218, 
224.214639928028, 14.7414363362227, 18.0511919451453, 21037.258121794, 
21659.968905852, 17721957.0100965, 41240.6588986806, 111.028537460958, 
21.7975275086975, 276.44178388089, 171.535750708364, 6.54776065462672, 
151.823636593007, 77.7232628471612, 378439.528032194, 8.9932059191815e-10, 
7.49689679316569e-08, 0.0155924907385915, 1032.31959077079, 69.010587250471, 
3136.70323628637, 249713.871697334, 19360.5708508639, 40.7258690163879, 
0.0162957051889601, 1.02869393872855e-06, 0.025268197376688, 
0.528481476061038, 0.982629085096339, 9.45655313066933e-07, 4.57557582847333e-05, 
7.45403294058092e-05, 4.53918933391971, 3.30530837062386e-13, 
0.630234341296706, 9.82668496529192e-08, 8.53389810467837e-08, 
9.02891336492619, 5451.02888390797, 3.90681590706977, 329.545150676593, 
103.491400305633, 697.038514954349, 222.73520900148, 10798.3042798457, 
21.0644243649671, 43176.6607108169, 4235.53654423626, 3100.32036580987, 
0.474678829666085, 6.40621457829452, 122.637549472055, 43.0666245228938, 
12.0250322640284, 61440.278302552, 6788575.58160297, 51.9360282881212, 
769.96899739087, 7.59005145509618e-09, 2.43526615569376e-14, 
7.39725489778816e-07, 0.000232784090617743, 2.71678851958226e-05, 
7.42801688358956e-06, 0.000419885957835749, 13.5780839769886, 
3.32442709394189, 0.335486082296544, 3.94230896978352, 1.46425278783307, 
8.69549979650646, 596385.229504125, 0.000115943040096764, 3628.23773839244, 
49454.7726336256, 0.000504974333790079, 0.00995546823577904, 
0.233933121119438, 0.363364289185792, 9193.93256769758, 354.456908896329, 
5661.68504768727, 0.121589829029783, 940.93343158607, 2.03003608173289e-18, 
0.0149649659043151, 4.52682955802236e-10, 7.15334079727642e-09, 
0.000310851843411754, 1.93389728243117e-06, 2.03883508956486e-07, 
0.00284517176384008, 540.061334125012, 21318282.1015595, 14894.4660549342, 
0.000266471541489485, 0.246672590081899, 0.102617416010794, 30584.5294303485, 
1.6644151457974, 0.274144521451231, 5.61250055231602, 801087.819256331, 
649321.765215902, 1.09526223361541, 3.19905699111348e-05, 0.383890848761449, 
895.643897487244, 2.68459116542856, 26.4804232740359, 5.94041739131986, 
1.53119475830081e-07), effect = c(-0.0048929408170183, 0.0543448544236634, 
0.355139910284011, -0.0793902472151885, -0.0177086113171934, 
-0.0229346227548993, 0.0859476877708055, 0.0616530901499479, 
0.0255808327961239, 0.0587050814255305, 0.0141476490245787, 0.016845032477233, 
0.0534824934671667, 0.109055235276048, 0.111112652283139, 0.0234941463950778, 
0.0509358202565552, 0.0252735688725701, 0.0359067099796669, 0.00562271637183446, 
0.0507704293161921, 0.17283228087345, 0.16140675832248, -0.0818286747635847, 
-0.00755469414427661, -0.0104447567093411, -0.128088271682644, 
-0.0534210973538898, -0.373370146687058, -0.0158548424704536, 
-0.0748163315974356, -0.0904460324042191, -0.0028512716452736, 
0.014271561838011, -0.00190156753813359, -0.0239279177026479, 
-0.0094336807819733, 0.0222425549129021, 0.0292506342181443, 
0.0325754202368439, 0.0148015986703938, 0.0421882264651577, 0.423260142208342, 
0.0203382101649578, 0.00402969463133637, 0.0866038959569813, 
-0.0126180724522637, -0.00101624925914612, 0.0424729539424711, 
0.0109268890743347, -0.100768815837666, -0.00606344260837149, 
-0.0909174554780339, -0.0959700647301915, -0.0768705808220001, 
-0.0662807953036616, -0.00706464147110935, -0.0260825101925435, 
-0.116360501719279, -0.0685817739681672, 0.0190371136722137, 
0.314176452865903, 0.0852019981707266, -0.109955683402951, -0.0429494359040651, 
-0.018893257986317, 0.0359280715736875, -0.00777719486360404, 
0.0268854711195253, 0.035717165605315, -0.0185632636448169, 0.00219893106540051, 
-0.0575168050187894, -0.0268860255228866, -0.0120997481434518, 
-0.0174770295188239, -0.0365387268315564, 0.00427667014560775, 
0.0290413811465955, -0.0303874959875708, 0.0494496371834744, 
-0.0172878730121681, -0.0596619493875312, 0.0674472930186462, 
0.0581172695200586, 0.0352865160196343, -0.0390338901505756, 
0.0201101954340249, 0.0968644367520139, -0.00587675128187206, 
-0.0990223012750421, -0.022532243059551, -0.109508938534005, 
-0.0828800247402709, -0.0224991372217077, -0.0864470271893071, 
-0.0120276456354962, -0.171616504240665, -0.0405716645109222, 
-0.150207882114913, 0.019187309212901, 0.0583618216547288, 0.312977089073896, 
-0.116708039798045, -0.0727212548658722, -0.0334904589242441, 
0.0250211767009604, -0.0262773156800457, -0.00638328497889965, 
0.0207436409328599, 0.00526977878443117, 0.0121248749949723, 
0.0372084648778052, 0.0119773388777849, 0.0299841410899367, 0.0179852238184209, 
0.00615922907815808, 0.0923011852715508, 0.0286655081413075, 
0.0615892570124506, -0.040101427234219, 0.00471273799312188, 
-0.0695325837078327, -0.0194435878635383, -0.0113447270023325, 
-0.052896201189637, 0.15391622949438, 0.0625317280746324, 0.305195811975115, 
0.0175140430499281, 0.0944330305254164, 0.125486034995771, 0.204097960624017, 
0.0139041133925463, 0.115503245160239, 0.0744749299835659, 0.0309401153645095, 
0.0774734185854047, 0.128577840642144, -0.00523940764293137, 
-0.0826725654792668, 0.00061718469555555, -0.139447399226457, 
-0.015892803158233, -0.0776351210087576, -0.114375795737603, 
0.506655172546014, 0.0139569906287469, 0.032593809131997, 0.0838209562382717, 
0.026889024005808, 0.114847700394033, 0.0344957168306127, 0.309849172983949, 
0.224583305802426, 0.0920680732068372, 0.20205450223499, 0.129261938040113, 
0.118741527574873, 0.0666598681717314, -0.0259685736746482, -0.00493768230442141, 
-0.0513043909367941, -0.0228292902998043, -0.125120892334107, 
-0.0354061460089046, -0.145910823420589, -0.0505094213129978, 
-0.357522550450534, -0.0492725484140125, -0.00672879449498781, 
-0.00498836470563034, 0.0857101915123005, 0.245202106389044, 
0.0652610111098569, 0.00803793757485241, 0.0456354806905821, 
0.0567597911088563, 0.155069881077418, 0.0398552868265476), direction = c(-1, 
1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 
-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 
-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 
-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 
1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 
-1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 
-1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 
-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
    plotval = c(-4.65436783913808, 7.4638390305887, -0.166061251006543, 
    3.15451610300161, 3.32743565041216, -3.36193787665198, 8.34218160099397, 
    -0.45134660936061, -0.861806358039495, 3.14989059429165, 
    -0.385424005854277, -2.11343559832442, 0.699014672037075, 
    -0.497079129132047, -0.104056259146589, -2.02963110287305, 
    -3.7673992980343, 1.12925537854411, 0.744739988834407, -2.95268419318977, 
    -1.36623884628847, 4.98189411623867, 0.0868661499973576, 
    3.28662435286223, 0.351109352101632, -1.57943969693098, -0.688197955780953, 
    0.857822769551858, 1.73066263028667, -1.48883721139058, -0.380556286225031, 
    -1.78716235272839, -0.809302569419764, -6.02028725962301, 
    -5.84785296501876, -3.073500877557, -0.967454268269813, -5.38748192000237, 
    -5.57408775663275, -3.96068672995749, 7.50597726212444, 4.69864253925926, 
    4.14916000637992, -0.386038843759309, -3.20486151733282, 
    -0.780262082752201, -0.507578804102515, -4.59710189032113, 
    -2.67740750044583, -2.65866587397551, -0.670087259849411, 
    -2.95884232700787, 11.6925265676543, 3.11870850390026, 3.94744095721937, 
    2.72176024102353, 1.08835175932808, -1.49196040507446, -1.8073900579076, 
    2.66167617047025, 0.485938344726535, 6.59364503804761, 7.0712906280104, 
    0.431581837757606, 1.11157095694052, -3.19891287043981, -1.40630643990113, 
    -1.48093021354005, -2.35066396611971, -1.16853980119637, 
    -1.25650588425321, -4.32298913566366, -4.3356578288347, -7.24851167871111, 
    -4.61532559535481, -2.04543461904724, -1.33840723441989, 
    -2.4416036868115, -2.23435464751167, -0.816092795927033, 
    -2.18133938975974, -1.89055102413018, -5.57799649218455, 
    9.04608546234764, 7.12511846787433, 1.80708450523289, -3.01381416921109, 
    -1.83891572308132, -3.49647343200987, -5.39744266823951, 
    -4.28691815843339, -1.6098703601382, 1.7879268409032, 5.98771381910823, 
    1.59742573937338, 0.276970230656392, 0.00761038521452666, 
    6.02426713306055, 4.33955424293266, 4.12760869236016, -0.656978297958022, 
    12.4807880165375, 0.200497935929844, 7.00759296681644, 7.06885254695129, 
    -0.955635485860221, -3.73647848327309, -0.591822947332438, 
    -2.51791492529225, -2.01490426327141, -2.84325677575944, 
    -2.34778887382083, -4.03335556106781, -1.32354959550492, 
    -4.63524905089898, -3.62690843318892, -3.49140657316158, 
    0.323600137070818, -0.806601481409993, -2.08862346391581, 
    -1.63414083395139, -1.08008625029083, -4.78845317422705, 
    -6.83177865764632, -1.71546873469442, -2.88647323876581, 
    8.11975527988995, 13.6134535668385, 6.13092941593436, 3.63304670440456, 
    4.56594416664396, 5.1291271177969, 3.37686864914492, -1.13283849034736, 
    -0.521716813134629, 0.474325491909851, -0.595750658150867, 
    -0.165616059566562, -0.939294549263021, -5.77552687887169, 
    3.93575531635149, -3.55969573624066, -4.6942082095516, 3.29673069510235, 
    2.0019383089733, 0.630908284813054, 0.439657756641714, -3.96350131412125, 
    -2.54956344582082, -3.75294570645333, 0.915102752209537, 
    -2.97355889939168, 17.6924962428955, 1.82492426830489, 9.34420585704084, 
    8.14549108393769, 3.50744655283763, 5.71356659688074, 6.6906179005526, 
    2.54589150999432, -2.732443084933, -7.32875220486331, -4.17302493900107, 
    3.57434916575198, 0.607879106033299, 0.98877892542788, -4.48550180288597, 
    -0.221261659119412, 0.562020428705443, -0.749156396749516, 
    -5.90368012822885, -5.81245996063456, -0.039518112762786, 
    4.49497802290257, 0.415792240525927, -2.95213537116121, -0.428878156658466, 
    -1.42292492276573, -0.773816960869839, 6.81496956627369), 
    category = c("Measured", "Measured", "Measured", "Measured", 
    "Measured", "Measured", "Measured", "Measured", "Measured", 
    "Measured", "Measured", "Measured", "Measured", "Measured", 
    "Measured", "Measured", "Measured", "Measured", "Measured", 
    "Measured", "Measured", "Measured", "Measured", "Measured", 
    "Measured", "Measured", "Measured", "Measured", "Measured", 
    "Measured", "Measured", "Measured", "Measured", "Measured", 
    "Measured", "Measured", "Measured", "Measured", "Measured", 
    "Measured", "Measured", "Measured", "Measured", "Measured", 
    "Measured", "Measured", "Measured", "Measured", "Measured", 
    "Measured", "Measured", "Measured", "Measured", "Measured", 
    "Measured", "Measured", "Measured", "Measured", "Measured", 
    "Measured", "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", 
    "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", 
    "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", 
    "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", 
    "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", 
    "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", 
    "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", 
    "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", 
    "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", 
    "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", 
    "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", 
    "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", 
    "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", 
    "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", 
    "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", 
    "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", 
    "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", 
    "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", 
    "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", 
    "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", "Derived", 
    "Derived")), .Names = c("Measurement", "variable", "Pval", 
"effect", "direction", "plotval", "category"), row.names = c(21L, 
22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 
35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 
68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 
101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 
112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 141L, 142L, 
143L, 144L, 145L, 146L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 151L, 152L, 153L, 
154L, 155L, 156L, 157L, 158L, 159L, 160L, 181L, 182L, 183L, 184L, 
185L, 186L, 187L, 188L, 189L, 190L, 191L, 192L, 193L, 194L, 195L, 
196L, 197L, 198L, 199L, 200L, 221L, 222L, 223L, 224L, 225L, 226L, 
227L, 228L, 229L, 230L, 231L, 232L, 233L, 234L, 235L, 236L, 237L, 
238L, 239L, 240L, 261L, 262L, 263L, 264L, 265L, 266L, 267L, 268L, 
269L, 270L, 271L, 272L, 273L, 274L, 275L, 276L, 277L, 278L, 279L, 
280L, 301L, 302L, 303L, 304L, 305L, 306L, 307L, 308L, 309L, 310L, 
311L, 312L, 313L, 314L, 315L, 316L, 317L, 318L, 319L, 320L, 341L, 
342L, 343L, 344L, 345L, 346L, 347L, 348L, 349L, 350L, 351L, 352L, 
353L, 354L, 355L, 356L, 357L, 358L, 359L, 360L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: While your `head(mockdata)` is a great start, I think placing the output of `dput(mockdata)` may make this question more reproducible.

Comment: If you just need  for few graphs, I would export in svg, and do it with inkscape.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Option 1

Use facets

```
mockdata$type = ifelse(mockdata$variable %in% LETTERS[1:3], "1", "2")

ggplot(mockdata) + 
  facet_wrap(~ type, scales='free_x') +
  geom_tile(aes(variable, Measurement, fill = mockdata$plotval), colour = "dark red")  + 
  scale_fill_gradient2(limits=c(-20, 20),high = "firebrick3", low = "dodgerblue4") + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=28, angle=90), axis.text.y=element_text(size=28)) + 
  labs(title="", x="", y="", fill="")
```

[image]

Although this is not quite perfect, because dropping the unused x-axis categories from each facet requires specifying `scales='free_x'` - which unfortunately does not keep the boxes the same width in each facet.

## Option2

To remedy this we can also set `space="free_x"` in facet_grid. Which I think gives what you are looking for:

```
ggplot(mockdata) + 
  facet_grid(~ type, scales='free_x', space="free_x") +
  geom_tile(aes(variable, Measurement, fill = mockdata$plotval), colour = "dark red")  + 
  scale_fill_gradient2(limits=c(-20, 20),high = "firebrick3", low = "dodgerblue4") + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=28, angle=90), axis.text.y=element_text(size=28)) + 
  labs(title="", x="", y="", fill="")
```

[image]

## Option 3

An alternative solution is to create separate plots for each category, and arrange them together. Here I put them together using `cowplot::plot_grid`, which allows us to set the relative widths how we want them (although you may need to tweak the rel_widths values a bit to get it just right):

```
library(cowplot)
p1 <- ggplot(mockdata[which(mockdata$type=="1"),]) + 
  geom_tile(aes(variable, Measurement, fill = plotval), colour = "dark red")  + 
  scale_fill_gradient2(limits=c(-20, 20), high = "firebrick3", low = "dodgerblue4") + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=28, angle=90), axis.text.y=element_text(size=28),
        legend.position="none") + 
  labs(title="", x="", y="", fill="") 

p2 <- ggplot(mockdata[which(mockdata$type=="2"),]) + 
  geom_tile(aes(variable, Measurement, fill = plotval), colour = "dark red")  + 
  scale_fill_gradient2(limits=c(-20, 20),high = "firebrick3", low = "dodgerblue4") + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=28, angle=90), axis.text.y=element_blank()) + 
  labs(title="", x="", y="", fill="") 

plot_grid(p1,p2, nrow = 1,  rel_widths = c(1,2))
```

[image]

## Option 4

You can create an extra factor level in the data, which lies between the columns you want to separate, and then plot tiles for that column in white.

```
mockdata = rbind(mockdata, 
                 data.frame(Measurement=1:20, 
                            variable="", 
                            Pval = NA,
                            effect = NA,
                            direction = NA,
                            plotval = 0,
                            category = "Measured"))
mockdata$variable = factor(mockdata$variable, levels = c("A", "B", "C", "", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e","f"))

ggplot(mockdata, aes(variable, Measurement)) + 
  geom_tile(fill = NA, colour = NA)  + 
  geom_tile(data = mockdata[which(mockdata$variable==""),], fill = "white", colour = "white")  + 
  geom_tile(data = mockdata[which(mockdata$variable!=""),], aes(fill = plotval), colour = "dark red")  + 
  scale_fill_gradient2(limits=c(-20, 20),high = "firebrick3", low = "dodgerblue4") + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=28, angle=90), axis.text.y=element_text(size=28)) + 
  labs(title="", x="", y="", fill="")
```

[image]

Comment: It is true that this is sub-optimal. I had already tried this solution and thus the 'keep the same width' requirement. Is there a way to hard-code the width of the tiles that you know of?

Comment: Good enough I guess, although this also requires some tweaking. I don't actually have this simple labels and more complex labels make the height and width more difficult to adjust. I've accepted the answer but if any future reader of this comment has a better solution I would be interested in knowing about it.

Comment: Ok, I've added another way into the answer - that I think is probably the best for your purposes. It is the 2nd option in the above answer.  I will leave the other options there too, in case they are useful to others.