# Use facet_wrap in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I tried the approach in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40157419/3692817) to use facets to include white lines between "zones" of my heatmap. Here's the same problem I have using the ChickWeight dataset.

```
library(reshape)
library(ggplot2)
ChickWeight.long <- melt(ChickWeight, id = c("Chick", "Diet"))

#Non-split heatmap
ggplot(ChickWeight.long, aes(x = Chick, y = variable, fill=value)) +
  geom_tile(colour="white",size=0.1) + #add grid lines between the tiles
  xlab("Chick") + ylab("") + labs(fill = "weight") +  
  theme_minimal()
```

This is my original plot, I'd like vertical lines to better distinguish groups of things (in this case, chickens) in the x axis
[image: Heatmap without breaks]

```
#Attempt of split heatmap
ggplot(ChickWeight.long, aes(x = Chick, y = variable, fill=value)) +
  facet_wrap(~Diet) +
  geom_tile(colour="white",size=0.1) + #add grid lines between the tiles
  xlab("Chick") + ylab("") + labs(fill = "weight") +  
  theme_minimal()
```

This is what I get. I'd like the squished plots to be stretched the whole length. What am I doing wrong?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I made `Chick` a `numeric` variable and allowed the x scale to be free.

```
ChickWeight.long$Chick <- as.numeric(as.character(ChickWeight.long$Chick))

ggplot(ChickWeight.long, aes(x = Chick, y = variable, fill=value)) +
  facet_wrap(~Diet, scale = "free_x") +
  geom_tile(colour="white",size=0.1) + #add grid lines between the tiles
  xlab("Chick") + ylab("") + labs(fill = "weight") +  
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't know you can change scales like that! Good job mate! Maybe make the Chicks integer, because I think they are just Chicken id :)

Comment: Your solution also works by simply adding `scales="free"` to the OP's original plot command.

Comment: Thank you. But I was actually hoping to get them all aligned on the same row. To basically only add white lines in an otherwise single long heatmap. But this might not be possible with facets, and I'll just plot multiple plots in a grid

Comment: To have the facets aligned in a single row, add `nrow = 1` to your `facet_wrap`, or switch to `facet_grid`